# How to get the label on bar plot/stacked bar plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt, bar-chart

I have a very simple stacked matplotlib bar plot embedded in PyQt Canvas. I am trying to get the corresponding label of the bar area (rectangle) based on the click. But I would always be getting **_nolegend_** when I try to print the information from the event. Ideally I would like to see the corresponding label on the bar attached in the code.

For example when you click the *gray* bar it should print *a2*

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


def on_pick(event):
    print event.artist.get_label()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.setWindowTitle('Pick Test')

    fig = Figure((10.0, 5.0), dpi=100)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    canvas.setParent(w)

    axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # bind the pick event for canvas
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)

    p1 = axes.bar(1,6,picker=2,label='a1')
    p2 = axes.bar(1,2, bottom=6,color='gray',picker=1,label='a2')

    axes.set_ylim(0,10)
    axes.set_xlim(0,5)

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Simple stacked bar plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets a little tricky because `bar` is a complex plot object that is really composed of multiple components.

You can use [`get_legend_handles_labels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels) to get all the artists and labels for the axes. Then you can look so see which group your current artist belongs to.

So your callback may look something like this.

```
def on_pick(event)
    rect = event.artist

    # Get the artists and the labels
    handles,labels = rect.axes.get_legend_handles_labels()

    # Search for your current artist within all plot groups
    label = [label for h,label in zip(handles, labels) if rect in h.get_children()]

    # Should only be one entry but just double check
    if len(label) == 1:
        label = label[0]
    else:
        label = None

    print label
```

Comment: Thanks @Suever, that worked. You are right, It is pretty complicated when compared to a stacked area plot which would work straight by getting the value of _event.artist.get_label()_